# Upsert (update or insert) of resources with generated URIs in REST?

Tags: rest

My data access layer supports the upsert operations (Spring Data's `CrudRepository.save()`), when the id field is not set a new record is inserted and when the id field is set it is updated.

I am wondering how to justify the additional effort required to create two separate REST methods (both on the backend and the frontend side):

- POST /users, for creating a new user (and generating the URI of the newly created resource)
- PUT /users/{id}, for updating the existing users

over creating just one REST method:

- POST /users

Are there any benefits of having two seperate methods other than being more RESTful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more clearer to using different resources for different actions.
By REST ideology - PUT Idempotent method and POST not Idempotent. So each POST request should return new item in response, but PUT should return the same item in response.

I think it's a good when behavior is expected.

But if you write documentation for your api, you can using one resource for both actions (but I would choose the first option).

Answer (score 0):

The data access layer supporting upsert does not mean that the REST API should support it, too. I would not overload `POST /users` with two meanings. Stick to two different resources.

**Edit:**

`POST /users` has the general meaning of 'add a new instance to the resource collection'. I see no way to extend this to '... or update existing instance if an ID is given'. `/users` is the *collection* resource, not a single resource you want to manipulate. Doing a `POST` to a collection resource should manipulate the collection, not a single existing resource.

Comment: How would you justify that? Convention?